# python xml.etree - how to search on more than one attribute

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file with this line:

```
<op type="create" file="C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/bld/armle-v7/release/SimpleNetwork/Makefile" found="0"/>
```

I want to use `xml.etree` to search on more than one attribute:

```
result = tree.search('.//op[@type="create" @file="c:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/bld/armle-v7/release/HmiLogging/Makefile"]')
```

But I get an error

> raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")

I tried this (added `and`), still got same error

```
'.//op[@type="create" and @file="c:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/bld/armle-v7/release/HmiLogging/Makefile"]'
```

Tried adding `&&`, still got same error

```
'.//op[@type="create" && @file="c:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/bld/armle-v7/release/HmiLogging/Makefile"]'
```

Finally, tried `&`, still got same error

```
'.//op[@type="create" & @file="c:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/bld/armle-v7/release/HmiLogging/Makefile"]'
```

I'm guessing that this is a limitation of `xml.etree`.

Probably I shouldn't use it in the future, but I'm almost done with my project.

For **`N`** attributes, how do I use `etree.xml` to be able to search on all **`N`** attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple square brackets in succession

```
'.//op[@type="create"][@file="/some/path"]'
```

**UPDATE**: I see that you are using python's `xml.etree` module. I am not sure if the above answer is valid for that module (It has extremely limited support for XPath). I'd suggest using the go-to library for all XML tasks -- [LXML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml). If you'd use `lxml`, it would be simply `doc.xpath(".//op[..][..]")`

Comment: How do I install lxml? I'm using Pycharm.

Comment: I haven't used PyCharm, but you'd generally do a: `pip install lxml` on a terminal